# WPF Button content based on DataContext settings

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working with WPF and MVVM pattern, I have a simple view which consists of a Button, which should display one thing or another depending on a property of the DataContext (viewmodel)
I've used datatriggers and datatemplates to try make this work, but for some reason the binding is not evaluating (or i'm doing something wrong).

```
    <Button x:Class="EpicNavalBattle.View.PositionView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 

        >
    <Button.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Hidden">
            <Label Content="Hidden"></Label>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Shown">
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Content.ContentName}" />
        </DataTemplate>



    </Button.Resources>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Revealed}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource Hidden}"></Setter>

                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Revealed}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource Shown}"></Setter>

                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Button.Style>


</Button>
```

Just to avoid confusion : Content is a property of the ViewModel (inherited datacontext) that's basicly the Model class, and ContentName, a property of the Model class.
The whole datatemplate IS evaluated, because to prove this, i changed the Content="Binding...." stuff for text, and it actually shows a button with the specified label inside.
right now, what i see is just buttons with no text (small, minimum size)
any help is appreciated (not only on how to solve this, but also on what i'm doing wrong here). thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested your code sample and the problem is this:

`ContentControls` such as Button, set their content as `DataContext` for the `DataTemplate`. So when you bind to the `DataContext`, you actually bind to the Content of your Button.

You can solve it in two ways:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=DataContext.Content.ContentName}
```

Or set the value as content in your trigger:

```
<Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content.ContentName}"></Setter>
```

This last solution would also be easier with the Hidden btw, so you can throw away these templates:

```
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Revealed}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content.ContentName}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Revealed}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
```

**Extra bonus: the ultra short solution:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Hidden" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Revealed}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content.ContentName}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: it didn't fix the problem, sorry. also, you don't say what you're based on to post the answer :)

Comment: alright! that's what i was talking about :). i'll use the first approach, not because it's more entangled that the 2nd one, but because now i was just trying to make it work, but i'll actually need to create some stuff inside the button (an image with some content). but thanks a lot for the detailed answer, and the main explanation on why this wasn't working

Comment: In _extra bonus short solution_ case if you set initial value ("Hidden") of the `Content` property by the `<Button.Content>` rather than inside the style (as in the code above) - it will not work! (style's trigger will not change the content) Be warned